# Ошибка LNK 2005 VISUAL STUDIO 2019

Tags: c

Здравствуйте возникает такая ошибка при запуске компилятора ругается на то что struct prog* head, * tail уже определены в Function.obj вот мои файлы кому не трудно гляньте в чем проблема

Function.cpp

https://pastebin.com/Mm9ut3Vq

Foo.h

https://pastebin.com/7ATf4qvX

Source.cpp

https://pastebin.com/wd9rzLWV

Comment: Наверняка в заголовочный файл внесли определение переменных...

Comment: Harry, я пробовал struct prog* head, *tail; запихнуть по спп файлам но все равно та же  ошибка , не подскажите как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Нужно запихнуть только в один cpp файл. А во втором сделать обьявление: `extern struct prog* head, *tail;`

Comment: Интересно, `cpp` теперь как си компилируется?)

Comment: ヒミコ, ну почему бы нет в вижуалке то нет именно под си приходится через костыли в спп

Comment: Вы так и не собираетесь следовать правилам *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.*?

Comment: @AlexK С в VS работает без проблем, достаточно выставить расширение файла на .c и / или использовать опцию `/TC`, `/experimental:preprocessor` / `/Zc:preprocessor`